# Representation of Fourier transform

Tags: signal-processing, fourier, laplace-transform

I have a problem interpreting 2 different representations of Fourier transform and proving their property.
In some texts Fourier transform is represented as:

$$
\begin{align*}
x(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} & \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{X(j\omega)e^{j\omega t}\,d\omega} \\
X(j\omega) = & \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x(t)e^{-j\omega t}\,dt
\end{align*}
$$

While in other texts the complex number \$j\$ is omitted in \$X(j\omega)\$. The problem comes when we try to prove things where the two notations don't work likely; for example, \$\frac{d}{d\omega}X(j\omega) = jX'(j\omega)\$, and \$\frac{d}{d\omega}X(\omega) = X'(\omega)\$.

I faced this confusion while proving the Duality property of Fourier transform; namely:

$$
\text{if}\;\mathcal{F}[x(t)] = X(j\omega),\;\; \text{then}\; \mathcal{F}[X(t)] = 2\pi\,x(-j\omega)\,
$$

in one representation and

$$
\begin{align*}
x(t) & \leftrightarrow X(j\omega) \\
X(t) & \leftrightarrow 2\pi\ x(-\omega)
\end{align*}
$$

in other representation.

I believe that in duality result of the former representation \$X(j\omega)\$ should contain additional \$j\$, i.e. \$X(t)\rightarrow 2\pi jx(-j\omega)\$, when i tried to prove it. But now I am confused.

Here is my proof, can someone validate that this is correct or correct it?
Notice the extra \$j\$ I am getting.

### Proof

$$
x(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{X(j\Omega)e^{j\Omega t}\,d\Omega}
$$

Replace \$t\$ with \$-j\omega\$, and \$j\Omega\$ with \$t\$ (just a change of variables),

$$
\begin{align*}
\Longrightarrow\; & 2\pi x(-j\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}X(t)e^{-j\omega t}\,d(t/j)\,, \\
\Longrightarrow\; & 2\pi jw(-j\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}X(t)e^{-j\omega t}\,dt\,,
\end{align*}
$$

So, I can say that \$\mathcal{F}\{X(t)\} = 2\pi jx(-j\omega)\$. END

---

Lot of articles or tutorials on google search uses this \$X(\omega)\$ notation instead of \$X(j\omega)\$.

I have found \$X(j\omega)\$ notation intuitive lot of times. Can some one please explain?

Comment: It should be \$j\omega\$ since the spectrum is made up of complex numbers. Maybe the reason you don't see it with *j* in other texts is due to a short-hand notation, probably explained or mentioned in the text, beforehand. If so, I don't find it a good approach. Best use \$X(j\omega)\$, that's how it's meant to be. Or write \$X(\omega)=...\$ but take care to not ignore the *j* in the right-hand side.

Comment: Don't write `d/dx X(jw)`. Write either `d/dw X()` or `d/djw X(.)`. that will make it clear whether you are differentiating with respect to `w` or `jw`.

Comment: I think people write `X(jw)` to highlight the fact that in the resulting transform `j` and `w` always appear together (at least if the original signal `x(t)`was purely real; I think).

Comment: If you can show the detailed steps you used to prove duality with both representation, perhaps we can find out if there is any error made in the calculations. Use the [edit] link below the question to add those details.

Comment: @AJN I have edited and added my version of proof, can you check it ? Also corrected the derivative variable.

Comment: There seems to three versions in your question 1) \$2\pi x(-\jmath\omega)\$, 2)\$ 2\pi x(-\omega)\$, and 3) \$2\pi \jmath x(-\jmath \omega)\$. Wikipedia has [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships,_one-dimensional) which i think matches with (2). Perhaps get this question migrated to Math.SE or MO, wherever it is appropriate.

Comment: @AJN I added this question on Maths Stackexchange <https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4119671/representation-of-fourier-transform>

Comment: Please don't cross-post the same question on multiple stacks.